Where is the prompt configured in ash's login shell?
I can login on an alpine based docker container by either a non-login or non-login shell, i.e. ash vs ash -l.
$ docker run -it --rm alpine /bin/ash
/ #

Now when I use the login shell, I see a weird string in the left on the prompt:
$ docker run -it --rm alpine /bin/ash -l
46d4c6007f75:/#

I wonder where that is coming from, I assumed it was the username but whoami says it is root.
I want to modify the appearance of the login shell for my alpine based container for the login shell, yet I have no clue where its defined.

Hunch: Could the string be docker's container id?

That is the container hostname, which by default is just a short version of the container id, but can be set to anything by using the --hostname option to docker run:
$ docker run -it --rm --hostname example alpine ash -l
example:/#

The prompt is defined by the PS1 shell variable, just like with Bash and other Bourne-like shells. By default, PS1 is set by /etc/profile and contains:
example:/# echo $PS1
\h:\w\$

But you can reset that as you see fit:
example:/# PS1='Moooooooo: '
Moooooooo: date
Wed Sep 11 02:22:16 UTC 2024
Moooooooo:


The difference is that both approaches set a different PS1 variable by sourcing different files.
The non-login uses:
\w \$
the login one uses:
\h:\w\$
\h means the hostname, \w the current directory.

But you haven’t answered your question!!
